# Как можно переписать данный метод в Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
const App = ({ Component, ...rest }: AppProps) => {
  const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppComponent Component={Component} props={props} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

App.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialAppProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ ctx, Component }) => {
      try {
        const userData = await Api(ctx).user.getProfile();
        store.dispatch(setUserData(userData));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error Authorization');
      }

      return {
        pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
          ? await Component.getInitialProps({ ...ctx, store })
          : {},
      };
    },
);
```

То есть, мне нужно, чтобы при инициализации приложения я получал данные  `await Api(ctx).user.getProfile();` и сохранял их в store, в моем случае это `pinia`.

**Я использую Nuxt 3, пишу на Composition Api, и использую pinia для хранилища**